# Javascript textContent returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

This is my code:

```
var text1 = "↵,<strong>bla bla</strong>";//here text1 has value
text1 = text1.textContent;//here it is undefined
```

Why? And how to resolve it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster Remove the tags.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use jQuery for such task.

First add reference to jQuery library, then it's as simple as this:

```
var text1 = "↵,<strong>bla bla</strong>";//here text1 has value
text1 = $("<div>").html(text1).text();
alert(text1);​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/5BsjQ/1/).

Comment: @RobG feel free to come with pure JavaScript then - I'm just suggesting something widely known and used to save hundreds of lines of self coding.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But for this value: "↵,Tils&aelig;t lidt fedt&nbsp;" it gives me error.

Comment: No need, there are already 2 good answers. Lines of code is not a metric clients care much about, nor is "less code" of any value in itself.

Comment: @RobG parsing HTML and removing tags might get very complicated. I would prefer to have one line of code to do that instead of learning long hours how to do that myself. (And end up failing)

Comment: @Srcee see my edit. My original code would give empty string back, no error. I fixed that anyway to handle such cases.

Comment: You can always create a function for it - then you do have a one-liner to do the job. See my answer for the non-jQuery code to do it.

Comment: @ThiefMaster forgot about the existence of `textContent` (too used to IE only innerText) are you sure this covers all cases including complicated HTML structures?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I'm pretty sure that's what jQuery does when using `.text()`

Comment: @ThiefMaster cheers, I'll leave this answer be as alternative for those already using jQuery anyway.

Comment: @Srcee please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10007292/447356) as well for a rather simple way without need for jQuery library.

Comment: @ShadowWizard—no one suggested parsing the HTML. I've added a very simple function to get the text, it's a couple of lines of basic code. How many hours? Oh, about 1 minute (as long as it took to type the characters).

Comment: @RobG this [has already been suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10007292/447356) and I have [notified the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007263/javascript-textcontent-returns-undefined/10007354#comment12795474_10007354) - more than that I can't really do, and like I said - if one is already using jQuery it's easier to use what it already has to offer so this answer does have value to other people thus I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 7):

`text1` is a plain string, not a DOM element.

As you can see [in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent), `textContent` is a property of `Node` objects. [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) objects on the contrary [do not have such a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Properties_2).

And since removing tags is a pretty simple task where it does not make sense to add a rather big library (even though jQuery **is** great as soon as you want to do more stuff with the DOM), here's a simple way to do it:

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = '<strong>hi &amp; bye</strong>';
alert(elem.textContent || elem.innerText || ''); // displays "hi & bte"
```

Comment: Not supported in IE8 and below. `elem.innerText || elem.textContent` should work though.

Comment: @thief—you can use `alert(elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '');`

Answer (score 4):

`text1` is a string, not a DOM node.

You would need to turn the HTML into a DOM (either by adding it to a document with `innerHTML` or by writing/finding a JS DOM parser) before you can use DOM methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have given you the answer, I'll just comment.

While [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) has been around since DOM 3 Core (about 8 years) most browsers have implemented the (MS proprietary) [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. So if you have a node, you can do:

```
var theTextContent = typeof node.textContent == 'string'? node.textContent : node.innerText;
```

or write a more robust function.

#### Edit

here's a full solution:

```
function getText(el) {
  return el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
}

var text1 = "<strong>bla bla</strong>"
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = text1;

alert(getText(d)); // bla bla
```